# Term for vertex connected to every other vertex in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Do you know a good common term for the operation of connecting a new vertex v to every vertex in a graph G (or a term for such vertex v)?

The ones I know give me poor search results:

- a nice word for v would be an *apex* vertex, but this usually only applies for planar G
- the operation is the *join* of G and a single vertex graph
- I have seen v called a *complete* vertex.

Comment: The analogous operation in topology is also called the join in general, and in this particular case is called the cone.

Answer (score 3):

The name I've usually seen for such a vertex is "universal vertex".

Comment: I've seen the term "dominating vertex" used, but probably prefer universal vertex.

Comment: Interesting Gordon.  As you can imagine though Gordon, I prefer dominating vertex!  Then, that concept I'm very familiar with!

Comment: That's (universal) the term I see most often and use myself --- but I have only picked it up somewhere a few years back.

Answer (score 2):

I've always called this operation taking the cone of a graph but I don't recall where I got that terminology from.

Comment: I do too. Must have picked it up from you. But I think the moral is that whatever you use, it will have to be defined.

Comment: I think this expression comes from the polytope world... at least this is where I first heard it, and there it is used with abundance.